# Using Zwoptex with Cocos2d's CCSpriteBatchNode on Retina Display

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I used the Zwoptex Flash version to generate:

- A .png texture file with -hd suffix (double sized images)
- A .png texture file without -hd suffix (normal sized images)
- A .plist file with -hd suffix.
- A .plist file with -hd suffix.

I have checked the files and everything seems to be there alright.

In my game, first I added the .plist file to the cache:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ParticleAnimations.plist"];
```

And then I created my CCSpriteBatchNode:

```
spriteBatch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"ParticleAnimations.png"];
[self addChild:spriteBatch z:0];
```

And finally create my CCSprite, with the filename of an image found in my textures:

```
CCSprite *particle = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Particle1.png"];
[spriteBatch addChild:particle z:0];
```

Now, I run this on the simulator (iPhone), and it runs just fine.
Then, I change the Hardware option and set it to "iPhone (retina)", which transforms the simulator on a 960x640 screen. But then, my gane crashes. Within the log, here are these entries:

> **cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'ParticleAnimations.png' as texture**
>
> **cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'Particle1.png' not found**

Which I don't quite understand. First of all, why is it using *ParticleAnimations.png* instead of *ParticleAnimations-hd.png*, since it is in Retina Display mode? And, of course, why is it looking for *Particle1.png* instead of *Particle1-hd.png*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To begin have you think to uncomment these lines into you appdelegate:

```
// Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

It'll enable Cocos2d to use the -hd files.

Then your sprite names must be exacty the same into your spritesheets. Just the plist and texture files must have the "-hd" suffix. For example if you have sprites named toto.png, titi.png, tata.png into your spritesheets named mysp it should look like that:

```
// Normal
- mysp.png
- mysp.plist
  |- toto.png
  |- titi.png
  |- tata.png

// Retina
- mysp-hd.png
- mysp-hd.plist
  |- toto.png
  |- titi.png
  |- tata.png
```

For more information, you should refer to the official documentation here: [RetinaDisplay in cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d)

I hope it'll help you!

Comment: "Then your sprite names must be exacty the same into your spritesheets" - Saved my butt, thanks!